# Want to know this light switch type, planning on getting a smart light switch

Tags: wiring, switch, light, smart-switch

this is my first post here, hope you can be of help.
I always wanted to put a smart light switch but there are many options online and for different wiring configuration.
I opened my light switch and the is what I found.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Could you please tell me what is that wire connected to the housing (the yellow and green wire)
And which type of smart light switch should I get. there are ones that need neutral and ones that dont and some need a hub and others capacitors. I only dont want to get the one with a capacitor since i dont think i have access to the lights wiring to install it.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the front of the switch? Does this switch operate independently or is there another switch somewhere so that you can control one light from two places? What country are you in (relates to wiring colors and some other issues)?

Comment: its independent. no other switches needed. I'm in the UAE. i added the front photo above. thanks

Comment: Based on comparison to other locations, it looks like you have 2 switches sharing hot with hot going on to elsewhere, plus switched hot for each switch. No sign of any neutrals.

Comment: and whats that green wire connected to the housing.

Comment: and based on that which type of smart switch should i get? thanks

Comment: The green wire is ground.  You probably want a smart switch that does not need neutral(most do) or can use ground.  You will want the instructions for the smart switch to state using ground is okay.  Not having a neutral at a switch box is a problem with smart switches, our newer electric code has fixed that by requiring a neutral wire.

Comment: Green is gtound, that's universal. Don't know enough about UAE practices to know what to get.

Comment: Green or green with a yellow stripe (as the OP has shown in his picture) is ground.

Comment: I agree it appears to be (2) single-pole switches with the hot daisy chained in and out of the box via the jumper between the switches and no neutral. But since it is fed by conduit it should be a rather simple task for an electrician to pull in a neutral. What jumps out as odd (by North American standards) is the hot in and out look like they go up the same conduit? So ring circuit?

Comment: If trying to locate a switch that the instructions say using the earth/ground wire as a neutral is an acceptable substitute I would expect the instructions would qualify that allowance with the statement "IF ALLOWED BY LOCAL CODES".